# Problems installing bonfire as it redirects me to the wrong page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create the right db on the phpMyAdmin then I unziped Bonfire in my root web directory.

The Index.php takes me to the install. I put the details right and then once I click test it takes me to `/install/install` I've tried putting the `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` file located at `bonfire/application/config/config.php` but i had no luck

Could anyone tell me why is it doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried installing Bonefire also and Had the same problem, I Fixed it by TURNING on my apache module the `rewrite_module`

Comment: It was enabled. Dont know why it didnt work. At the end  i just installed xamp instead of wamp and it worked. It was for my own test environment so.... but thanks for the help